# Default SELECTION pathway to an Outlook Email Template

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I select and use Outlook email templates every day.  The browsing path to find these templates is long, i.e.: New Items>More Items>ChooseForm.  It is not over then!  Once I have selected "Choose Form" I am delivered to a "Look In" field and have the choice of 13 folders to select from.  The default folder that is selected is "Organizational Forms Library".  My Outlook Email templates, however, are in the folder "Templates in File System".

Question:  How do I change this selection process so that the DEFAULT LOOK-IN folder selected is always "User Templates in File System" thereby shortening the process?? Thanks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change default "Look In" value. But you can optimize the pathway.

First of all, you can place "Choose Form" button right on Outlook ribbon. To do this, right-click on the ribbon, select "Customize the Ribbon", select "All Commands" in "Choose commands from" and find "Choose Form" button in the right list. Now you can create your custom group on the "Home (Mail)" tab and "Add>>" the button there. Now one click only needed to open the "Choose Form" dialog.

Second, you can create a VBA macro that will utilize the `Application.CreateItemFromTemplate` method to create a new item based on the template in file system and place the button on the ribbon. You can create separate button for each of most used templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can open an OFT template from a file folder using a macro that you can add to the Outlook Ribbon reducing your steps to a single click. (Thanks to thims for the lead, I just pulled the info together here for anyone less familiar with VBA).

**Enable the Developer tab in Outlook:**

1. On the File tab, go to Options > Customize Ribbon.
2. Under Customize the Ribbon and under Main Tabs, select the Developer check box.

**Create the VBA function**

1. Click the Developer tab, then Visual Basic
2. Right click the project and insert a module
3. Paste in the code below and then edit the sub name and path to the template as needed.  (Note that in the sample we are creating the object in the drafts folder, this parameter is optional and the function will work without specifying where to open the object)
4. Click the Run icon to verify the form opens (it may open under the developer window)
5. Once working, Click the Save button and close the Visual Basic window

```
Sub OpenTemplate_MySample()
    Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Set MyItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("c:\mypath\MySample.oft", _
                 Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts))
    MyItem.Display
End Sub
```

**Add the button to the Ribbon that runs the Macro**

1. Right click on the ribbon and select Customize the Ribbon
2. Click New Group under the right hand list, use the arrows to the right to position the new group and use Rename to give it a friendly name.
3. Under the left list *Choose commands from:* select *Macros*
4. The VBA code you created should be listed, select it and on the right make sure the new group is selected, then click the Add button between the lists
5. Click Ok to close the Outlook Options window

Verify the new ribbon button results in the OFT file opening as expected.